# How to get/read time from tktimepicker in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tktimepicker import AnalogPicker, AnalogThemes,constants
root = tk.Tk()
time_picker = AnalogPicker(root,type=constants.HOURS24)
time_picker.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
theme = AnalogThemes(time_picker)
theme.setDracula()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make use of `time` method (this returns tuple containing hours, minutes and period). Eg: `time_picker.time()`, alternatively you can make use of `hours()` to get hours, `minutes()` to get minutes and `period()` to get the period. Refer this [example](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkTimePicker/blob/master/examples/AnalogTimePickerExample.py)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkTimePicker/blob/master/Documentation.md) you need.

HOURS:

Methods: `getHours` -This takes no arguments and returns the current hour it is pointing to.

Events: `<<HoursChanged>>` - This event is generated when hours is changed.

MINUTES:

Methods: `getMinutes`- Takes no arguments and returns the current minutes.

Events: `<<MinChanged>>` - Generated when the minutes is changed.

[Examples](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkTimePicker/blob/master/examples/SpinTimePickerExample.py)